# How to uncheck all radio buttons from another class

Tags: python, layout, pyqt4, signals-slots

I want to uncheck some radio buttons in `class A` by pushing a button in `class B`.

My example codes are as below:

```
import sys, os

import PyQt4
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, bridge, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.bridge = bridge

        self.grid = QGridLayout()

        self.radiobtn = QRadioButton()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.radiobtn, 0, 0)

class Widget2(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid = QGridLayout()

        self.pushbtn = QPushButton()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushbtn,0, 0)

class Tab1Layout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = QGridLayout()

        self.group2 = Widget2()

        self.group1 = Widget1(self.group2, self)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.group1, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.group2, 1, 0)


class Tabs(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.tab1 = Tab1Layout()
        self.addTab(self.tab1, 'Tab1')

        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Tabs()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As my code is now, it has two problems:

1. The radio button and the push button don't show up
2. Let's say the radio button and the push button finally show up: I want that when I click the push button in `Widget2`, the radio button in `Widget1` should be unchecked if it is already checked.

Please note that I'm already linking `Widget1` and `Widget2` by putting a second argument `bridge` in `Widget1`. The reason I did this is because there's some other functions in my original project. So please don't alter this part if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons don't show up because you have not added the grid layouts to any of the widgets. So for **all three** grid layouts, do either this:

```
    self.grid = QGridLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.grid)
```

or this:

```
    self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
```

To check/uncheck the radio button using a button click, do this:

```
class Tab1Layout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        ...
        self.group2.pushbtn.clicked.connect(self.group1.radiobtn.toggle)
```

Comment: If I'm getting this right, so I can link two classes (let's say `A` and `B`) together in the third class `C` and then do all the actions between `A` and `B` in `C` as long as I set an argument (such as `bridge` in my example) in one of the two classes?  Even more, can I don't set a `bridge` at all?

Comment: @ryan9025. The `C` class knows about `A` and `B`, but `A` and `B` don't know about each other. If you connect all the signals between `A` and `B` inside `C`, then you won't necessarily need the bridge. That's the beauty of signals: the components don't need to know about each other; they just react to signals as and when they arrive. Did you ask another question that recommended using a "bridge"? If so, it might be possible to solve it without one.